# Алгоритм Дейкстры: отрицательное ребро на примере

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Вопросик по алгоритму Дейкстры - Я знаю, что этот алгоритм не допускает отрицательных весов. В данном графе есть одно ребро с отрицательным весом, но ведь алгоритм все равно правильно считает кратчайшие пути или я что-то не замечаю?

[image]

Comment: Как бы это выразить... словом, если на заборе надпись "осторожно, злая собака!", а вы перелезли через забор и назад целым и невредимым - то основание ли это считать, что надпись неверна и можно лазить сколько угодно? :) При отсутствии отрицательных весов алгоритм дает гарантию поиска правильного пути. При наличии - нет. Например, замените 9 и 4 на любые отрицательные значения :) Но это не значит, что алгоритм не будет работать ВСЕГДА.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я в принципе понимаю, почему не должно быть отрицательных значений, но вот это конкретный пример сбил меня с толку, и я хотел узнать, правильно ли я понимаю конкретно данный пример и что несмотря на отрицательное значение, алгоритм работает в данном конкретном случае без ошибок..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если исключить из рассмотрения тривиально некорректные постановки задачи (т.е. наличие в графе цикла отрицательного веса), то неприятие алгоритмом Дейкстры ребер с отрицательным весом базируется на *жадной* природе алгоритма: алгоритм идет по *пути наименьшего сопротивления*, в процессе своей работы помечает некоторые вершины как "уже проанализированные" и гарантирует что кратчайшие пути ко всем этим "уже проанализированным" вершинам *окончательно найдены*. Т.е. алгоритм критически завязан на тот факт, что ребра, содержащиеся в еще не просмотренной части графа, никак не могут улучшить (сократить) пути к "уже проанализированным" вершинам.

Но как только в графе появляются отрицательные ребра, в общем случае уже нет никакой возможности гарантировать то, что пути, построенные по такой стратегии *наименьшего сопротивления* для какого-то подмножества "уже проанализированных" вершин, являются кратчайшими: всегда есть опасность, что где-то в еще непросмотренной части графа прячется альтернативный, еще не найденный путь с лучшим весом.

Как обычно, для того, чтобы обмануть *жадный* алгоритм, необходимо "спрятать" оптимальное решение за некоей локальной "горкой". *Жадный* алгоритм не полезет в горку, а пойдет по *пути наименьшего сопротивления* в другом направлении:  он либо никогда не найдет "спрятанного" оптимального решения, либо найдет его слишком поздно. В соответствии с этой стратегией, чтобы сломать алгоритм Дейкстры, нужно чтобы в процессе просмотра вершин вдруг оказалось, что за внешне "непреспективным" (тяжелым)  ребром скрываются настолько отрицательные ребра, что они порождают улучшенный путь к вершине, которую алгоритм считает "уже проанализированной".

Например, положите веса `W(s, x) = 100` и `W(v, y) = 3`. При поиске путей из вершины `s` алгоритм Дейкстры будет работать неправильно. Порядок обработки вершин тогда будет таким: `s`, `v`, `y`, `x` ... Результат для вершины `y` будет зафиксирован еще до того, как алгоритм обнаружит ребро `(x, y)`. И если кратчайший путь в вершину `y` через вершину `x` еще есть шанс "спасти", на результат для вершины `t` он в рамках алгоритма Дейкстры уже не повлияет.